# ChartJS and Flask, how to pass data?

Tags: javascript, flask, chart.js

I want to draw a chart using ChartJS and Flask.

I can draw the chart when I set my variables directly into the JS part (i.e. when data: `[1.03, 380.31, 0.0, 18.69, 400.02]`), but not when I pass the data using Flask.

I have checked the variable passed to Flask, and I can show in the browser (with a `p` tag) that the content of the array is fine: `[1.03, 380.31, 0.0, 18.69, 400.02]`

The JS code is below, `t_gamme` and `t_badge` are both arrays (build in Python using append method):

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("chart-tps"), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "TOTAL"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "Temps gamme (h)",
      backgroundColor: "#3e95cd",
      data: "{{ t_gamme }}"
    }, {
      label: "Temps badgé (h)",
      backgroundColor: "#8e5ea2",
      data: "{{ t_badge }}"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Temps badgé versus temps gamme en heures'
    }
  }
});
```

I would like avoiding to make an AJAX call to an endpoint for getting these arrays because I have already.

I removed `"` character and it works, but I have errors in Javascript code in Visual Studio Code:
[image: Errors when removing " character]

Related to ChesskoWarrior's answer:

I tried that solution, but still, get the red error on double brackets.
[image: Errors on double brackets]

Comment: Have you tried adding | safe to your jinja variable? So, {{ t_badge | safe }}?

Comment: In fact, I only removed the " character, and it works, but I have errors in my Javascript (underlined in ref in Visual Studio Code), but it works. Have you got a better solution avoiding the red errors in Visual Studio Code? Errors are 'Property assignment expected.javascript', or 'expected.javascript'.

Comment: I think that is just VSCode telling you it’s invalid JS, happens when you use Jinja in JS. There might be a setting to suppress it, but not sure off the top of my head

Comment: It works, and if it is fine from a web standard, that is Good enough. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that works for me:

1.) Python function in routes.py as part of the Flask-App:

```
def index():
    data = {"labels": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
            "data_1": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
            "data_2": [5, 6, 7, 8]}
    return render_template('template.html', data=data)
```

2.) You can access this variable in template.html as {{ variable }}. This works in JS too. However, you need to create a new JS variable and make sure the data is formatted in the right way. Fortunately, there is a Jinja "tojson"-filter which converts the data into a proper JSON (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#standard-filters). Knowing this, this code snippet works for me inside the template.html:

```
{% block javascripts %}

  <script>
    var data_js = {{ data|tojson }};
    ...
    });    
  </script>

{% endblock javascripts %}
```

Now you can access the data using the original keys:

```
datasets: [{
      label: data_js["labels"],
      data: data_js["data_1"]
    }, {
      label: data_js["labels"],
      data: data_js["data_2"]
    }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and your nice idea, but I have still the same eror when I use the double brackets (please find the picture in my original post).

Comment: I'm afraid you are mixing labels (x axis on a lines graph) with label (title of each line).